# right to left drop down menu in css

Tags: css, html

here is my code:

```
    <div class="menu-container">

<a class="toggleMenu" href="#">תפריט</a>
<ul class="nav">
    <li  
  <a href="#">טיפול בחרדות</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.bkalut.co.il/Test-anxiety.html">חרדת בחינות </a>

                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="http://www.bkalut.co.il/social-anxiety.html">חרדה חברתית </a>

</li>
            <li>
<a href="http://www.bkalut.co.il/Anxiety-in-children.html">חרדות אצל ילדים </a>

            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.bkalut.co.il/Anxiety-Attack.html">התקף חרדה </a>

            </li>

            </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and this is the css

```
body, nav, ul, li, a  {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
a {text-decoration: none;}
.menu-container {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
.toggleMenu {
    display:  none;
    background: #666;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #fff;
         float:right;

}
.nav {
    list-style: none;
     *zoom: 1;
     background:#175e4c;
}
.nav:before,
.nav:after {
    content: " "; 
    display: table; 
}
.nav:after {
    clear: both;
}
.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 9em;
}
.nav a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color:#fff;
}
.nav li {
    position: relative;
}
.nav > li {
    float: right;
    border-top: 1px solid #104336;
}
.nav > li > .parent {
    background-image: url("images/downArrow.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}
.nav > li > a {
    display: block;

}
.nav li  ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}
.nav > li.hover > ul {
    left: 0;
}
.nav li li.hover ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
.nav li li a {
    display: block;
    background: #1d7a62;
    position: relative;

    z-index:100;
    border-top: 1px solid #175e4c;
}
.nav li li li a {
    background:#249578;
    z-index:200;
    border-top: 1px solid #1d7a62;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .active {
        display: block;
    }
    .nav > li {
        float: none;
    }
    .nav > li > .parent {
        background-position: 95% 50%;
    }
    .nav li li .parent {
        background-image: url("images/downArrow.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 95% 50%;
    }
    .nav ul {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
   .nav > li.hover > ul , .nav li li.hover ul {
        position: static;
    }

}
```

i want the drop dow menu will be alighn to right i try many options but didnt't succedd to do this.
i'll explain:
i need all the drop down menu than in the code begin in the second  will begin from roght to left and not from left to right. i need all the alighnment from right tom left so that the drop down menu will begin from the right side of the main menu above and not from the left side.
thank you.

Comment: have you tried [`text-align:right`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)? or this one [`direction:rtl;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction)?

Comment: where should i put them?

Comment: these are CSS attributes. an example of where to put them is `.nav li { direction:rtl; }`

Comment: i put it in .nav li li a
it solve the problem of the text alighnment but not the problem of the drop down menu alignment it still apear from the left side of the main menu and not from it's right side

Comment: if you want to align elements use `float:right;`

Comment: i try it - not solve the problem still the drop down menu begin from the left side and more bad -  all the lines in the drop down menu ends where the text end  and not in the same line

Comment: Please provide me a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and i will help you further

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8tsBN/
but it not show it properly

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8tsBN/1/ is this how its supposed to work?

Comment: Here you go, i think this is what you want http://jsfiddle.net/8tsBN/2/

Comment: no it is an responsive menu. in it's computer view it  has two tawbs in the main menu and the drop down menu go below it.

Comment: thank you very much!!!
it's ok 
you solve my problem!!!

Comment: No problem, have a good one.